# how to implement JsonP in cakephp 2.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have just upgraded to cakephp 2.4.1 as it now supports JsonP. I was previously getting an a missing callback error in my ajax cross domain code. However the documentation does not mention any additional steps need to implement this so I would have thought that it should wold but i get the same error as before.

Do I need an extra piece of code to send the callbck back?

My Controller

```
public function api($mem_id = null) {
    $options = array(
        'fields' => array('Member.total_points'),
        'conditions' => array('Member.member_no' => $mem_id),
        'recursive' => -1
    );
    $members = $this->Member->find('first', $options);
    $this->set(array(
        'member' => $members,
        '_serialize' => array('member')
    ));
}
```

}

ajax code

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mydomain.com/loyalty/members/api/5749.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(resonse);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: For anyone coming across this page that doesn't have a complete understanding of how`JSONP` works with CakePHP, I've written a [full example/answer over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28963737/366529)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should have worked fine with the older Cake version too, just as I've described in your other question ;)

Anyways, look at the code in [`/lib/Cake/View/JsonView.php`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.0/lib/Cake/View/JsonView.php#L87) or in the [API documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-JsonView.html#_render). You have to define a view var named `_jsonp`, which can be either a string specifying the name of the query variable that holds the callback function name, or `true` which means a default query variable with the name `callback` is being looked up.

So as jQuery uses a query variable name of `callback` by default, defining `true` for `_jsonp` should do it:

```
$this->set(array(
    'member' => $members,
    '_serialize' => array('member'),
    '_jsonp' => true
));
```

In case no query variable named `callback` could be found in the request URL (ie `?callback=whatever`), you'd receive a regular JSON response instead.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > JSON and XML views > JSONP response](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#jsonp-response)**

Comment: Thanks -- something that I was missing was the .json extension in the url of my ajax call. Without the .json extension I was receiving a server error. Without having done much investigation, I think it had something to do with the values passed in headers/accept when no extension is included in the url.

Answer (score -1):

If that just don't work, try to change the value of **$jsonpParam** from "*callback*" to "*jsoncallback*" (in *lib/Cake/View/JsonView.php*). I had to do that for make it work, thats because the name of the variable in the jsonp request, is **jsoncallback**, this one contains the string of the callback.

Comment: Don't change any files in the `lib` directory that don't belong to you. When you update or restore Cake, or share your repo with someone else, those files you changed will be overwritten and you almost certainly won't remember what changes you made to them to make them work. I'm not sure if your approach of changing `callback` to `jsoncallback` is correct, but if you have to do it, extend any Cake class you want to change and make your changes in your own class.