# Cross domain ajax request not detecting in Cakephp 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cross-domain

How to detect cross domain ajax request in Cakephp 2.7.

I am sending request from my one domain to another domain.

**jQuery Aajx : From my one domain http:// firstdomain.com**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://anotherdomain.com/users/profile/' + id,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            //crossDomain: true,
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
            success: function(result) {


            }
    });
```

**CakePHP Controller to my another domain https:// anotherdomain.com which have ssl installed**

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Js', 'Paginator');
    public $components = array('Email', 'RequestHandler');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }


    public function profile($id) {
        //$this->request->onlyAllow('ajax'); // No direct access via browser URL
        $this->layout = false;
        $this->autoRender = false;

        echo $this->request->is('ajax'); die; //no output here. but $this->request->is('post') true

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to checkout `jsonp` request fro cross-domain.Or use `CURL`

Comment: @AlivetoDie i can do only Ajax , CURL is not possible.... can you make some ans?

Comment: Diffrent helpful links:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/28963737/4248328 And  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18817427/4248328  And  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246063/simple-ajax-json-response-with-cakephp